# is it possible to put files in the android filesystem in install time?

Tags: android, file-io

I'm very new to android. I would like to create a package that upon install would put files in the app folder (/data/data/my.app/...) of the android file system.

I would like to do this, so I could access the files using standard java File methods (in order to reuse my own code), and not have to use the android resource accessing methods.

The only way I thought might achieve something in this direction, is to put the files in the /res folder, and copy them to the file system in runtime (on first run, for example). This has the disadvantage of having two copies of each file for no reason.

Another way could be to get my app to download these files from a server (saw this option in another answer as well). This is possible, but I would wish to avoid having to put up a file server for such a simple task...

To my understanding, DDMS will not help here, as it only allows me to access the folder manually, after the application is installed.

My question is: Is there a different way to achieve my original goal (accessing files using standard java methods)? If not, is there a cleaner way to put files on the file system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 methods I can think of that avoid duplication:

1. As you mentioned using the res/raw folder. You can avoid duplication if your existing code uses can use [InputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html) instead of [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) and use [Resources.openRawResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29).
2. Use the assets folder and access the file using file using [AssetManager.openNotAssetFd()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#openNonAssetFd%28java.lang.String%29). Again this would require the use of Streams not File class. This can get a bit messy if your file is compressed because assets are memory mapped.
3. If you code is really tied to [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) (doesn't just use it to open an [InputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html)). To avoid duplication you could download the file from the web on the first time it is run and store it into the external storage.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! From your response I gather that there isn't really a "correct" way to do this. Since what I needed was a complete directory structure, created from outside of my project (and not just a set of a few files), it seemed like using the Asset mechanism was the right way. For now, I just copied them recursively to the filesystem (resulting in duplication). If they'll become too big, I guess I'll switch to downloading them from the web. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can put your files on under /res/raw and then use:

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.myfile);
```

Or if you want the File object

```
File f = new File(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myfile));
```

Then you can use normal Java apis to work with your files.